# Passing a number to a field on a website via hyperlink or script?

Tags: html, hyperlink

On the page I want to pass a number to, the "inspect element" of the field shows me this:

```
<input type="number" name="offeramount" minimum="1" id="amount" value="0">
```

I tried to create a hyperlink in my spreadsheet with either of the following:

```
https://example.com/nation/trade/create?amount=5
https://example.com/nation/trade/create?offeramount=5
```

But both gave me a "page not found" error.

Is this possible to pre-fill the field using just the hyperlink in my spreadsheet, or will I have to run a Google script or something?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function gup( name, url ) {
  if (!url) url = location.href
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( url );
  return results == null ? null : results[1];
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("amount").value = gup("offeramount");
}
```

put this in a script tag inside the body.

After that, put '?offeramount=5' at the end of the url, and it should do the trick.